# creating dynamic lineseries in linechart

Tags: apache-flex, arraycollection, linechart

This is my array collection

```
 [Bindable]private var Projects:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection( [
                { Department: "Software", TotalProjects: 73,Completed:30,Inprogress:30,Approved:13},
                { Department: "XML",TotalProjects: 50,Completed:20,Inprogress:20,Approved:10},
                { Department: "Publishing",TotalProjects: 25,Completed:5,Inprogress:10,Approved:10},
                { Department: "Indesign", TotalProjects: 70,Completed:30,Inprogress:30,Approved:10},
                { Department: "Imaging", TotalProjects: 42,Completed:30,Inprogress:10,Approved:2}]);
```

line series for line chart:

```
<mx:series>


<mx:LineSeries id="cs1"
                                   yField="TotalProjects"
                                   xField="Department"
                                   displayName="TotalProjects">

                </mx:LineSeries>
                <mx:LineSeries id="cs2"
                               yField="Inprogress"
                               xField="Department"
                               displayName="Inprogress">

                </mx:LineSeries>
                <mx:LineSeries id="cs3"
                               yField="Completed"
                               xField="Department"
                               displayName="Completed">

                </mx:LineSeries>
                <mx:LineSeries id="cs4"
                               yField="Approved"
                               xField="Department"
                               displayName="Approved">

                </mx:LineSeries>


            </mx:series>
```

how can i create `mx:LineSeries` dynamically depending upon array collection values. Now only 4 line series is there but some times i have to show more as per the array collection values change ex: if one more status `HoldProject` added to array collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var series:Array=[];
for (var prop:String in Projects[0])
    if (prop != "Department") {
        var ls:LineSeries=new LineSeries();
        ls.yField=prop;
        ls.xField="Department";
        s.displayName=prop;
        series.push(ls);
    }
myChart.series=series;
```

In this case, each item in your dataProvider should have the same property set.

Comment: OK.if i receive array collection objects with different properties each time how to loop over array collection items and create line series?

Comment: Could you please give more details? Because, how can we know, what field should be used in each item as yField?

Comment: @ Timofei Davydik in array collection given `Department`  is common  but remaining fields are changing sometimes only 3 status:`Completed`, `hold`,`approved` and some times more `Completed`, `hold`,`approved`,`deleted`,`initial`,`deferred` etc.

Comment: @ Timofei Davydik it is nice but in `prop` instead of attribute(Department), value(software) is getting retrieved. how to get attribute from projects[0]?

Comment: @M.S.Nayak are you sure, you've copied the code? In my code `for...var` loop is used, it retrieves properties/attributes. And `for each...var` loop retrieves values. Please, make sure, you're using `for...var`.

Comment: @ Timofei Davydik ok I used for each. ya working fine thank you.